# How do I find Authorised Devices

Tags: authorization

I have an iPod and iPad which I sync with my Mac.
My wife has has an iPod, iPhone  and iPad which she syncs with her Mac.

These are all associated with the same Apple ID.

I am planning to buy an iPhone, basically to replace my iPod.

I understand there is a limit to the number of devices, although I have not been able to discover the devices associated with my Apple ID.

http://support.apple.com/en-au/ht4627 has instructions which I have followed.

There are 3 computer authorisations listed, but there seems to be no `Manage Devices` on the `Account Information screen`.

NOTE We do not use automatic downloads or iTunes Match. I am only interested in `apps`

Comment: Have you downloaded any apps purchased on one device onto another device? The page says the device does not become associated with your Apple ID until you download a past purchase (or enable Automatic Downloads or iTunes Match, which you state you do not use).

Comment: I just checked in iTunes, and Manage Devices appears under the "iTunes in the Cloud" section, which is not far from Computer Authorizations, but not right next to it either, as you might expect.

Comment: @tubedogg All this shows me is Hidden Purchases. We do have a few purchased apps on all our iDevices

Comment: Maybe try enabling automatic downloads, and then disabling it, on each device, to see if that causes the device to become associated with the Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

These articles on https://www.apple.com/support/itunes/authorization/ should help with authorization needs. In my understanding, you must de-authorize all devices and not just one. The limit is 5, so you still have room.

Comment: The limit is five computers _in a pool of ten_ combined devices and computers. See "[Associating a device or computer to your Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht4627)".

Comment: That makes sense. It seems familiar, actually. Thanks for that.